# List Concatenation, Adding elements that finish with ':' to a list, and others to a sublist

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, concatenation

I need to format the output of a list in order to have all elements that finish with `:` as first elements, while the rest in a sublist of that list.
For example:

Suppose we have:

```
A: B, C
B: D, F | G
```

What i have done until now transforms that in the following list:

```
['A:', 'B,', 'C', 'B:', 'D,', ['F', 'G']]
```

But now i don't know how to arrive to the following output:

```
[['A:',['B', 'C']], ['B:', ['D', ['F', 'G']]]
```

Can you help me?

Edit:
Here a I read the file:

```
file = open('data.txt', 'r')
Y = []
for line in file:
    for word in line.strip().split():
        Y.append(str(word))
```

This part is where i put the ors inside a sublist:

```
text = []
i = 0
while True:
    if i > len(Y)-2:
        # No more possible |'s, so wrap things up
        text.append( Y[-1] )
        break
    if Y[i+1] == '|':
        # Add the items around the |; move past the group:
        if Y[i+2].endswith(','):
            Y[i+2] = Y[i+2].replace(",", "")
            text.append([Y[i], Y[i+2]])
        else:
            text.append([Y[i], Y[i+2]])
        i += 3
    else:
        # Add the current element & move on
        text.append( Y[i] )
        i += 1
for id in range(len(text)-1):
    if type(text[id]) != str:
        if text[id][-1] == text[id+1]:
            text.remove(text[id+1])
```

Comment: What do you have as input ? a string or a dictionary ?

Comment: Whats the format of your input?

Comment: The input( A,B..) is taken from a file, and then i put everything in a list as strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you split your word first and put them within a list? you can directly loop over your line and split them with one nested list comprehension :

```
import re
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f :
     [[k,[p,n.split('|')]] if '|' in n else [k,[p,n]] for k,(p,n) in [[i,j.split(',')] for i,j in [re.split(r'(?<=:) ',line) for line in f]]]
```

result :

```
[['A:', ['B',' C']], ['B:', ['D', [' F ', ' G']]]]
```

But note that this is not a general solution! as a more general way if its possible that you have some other delimiters instead of `|` fro example if it would be a none word character you cal split the `n` variable with regular expression (`re.split(r'\W',n)`).

*Note*: `r'(?<=:) '` is a [positive look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that will split your lines based on the space that came after `:`.

If you don't want to split the lines with `regex` you can use `str.partition` :

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f :
    [[k,[p,n.split('|')]] if '|' in n else [k,[p,n]] for k,(p,n) in [[i+j,t.split(',')] for i,j,t in [line.partition(':') for line in f]]]
[['A:', [' B',' C']], ['B:', [' D', [' F ', ' G']]]]
```

Comment: I can't use external modules... just basic python operations
Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm getting the following error :``NameError: name 's' is not defined``, but i will try to figure out why! :)

Comment: @BioShock Sorry it remained from may last try ,Checkout the edit! ;)

Comment: I tried to figure out this for like 2 days. I'm still a novice! I really appreciated! (sorry for my english)

Comment: I just realised that in your output there is a small mistake  in the first sub list: ``['A:', [' B', [' C']]]``, actually it creates a new sublist containing ``C`` while what I needed what the following: ``['A:', [' B', ' C']]`` since there is no **or**. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @BioShock Yeah, i add a condition to list comprehension.

Comment: The first listcomp is still wrong, you only edited the result and second listcomp.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a homework assignment to parse a context-free grammar, and the `|` separates expansions. So here's some advice:

1. Each line is a rule with left and right sides. So split lines (you already read one line at a time) and process each one separately.
2. Each line has a left side separated by `:` from the expansions. Split on `:`.
3. A right side can have multiple expansions separated by `|`. Split and process each one.
4. An expansion can have multiple tokens separated by `,`. Split on this, discard whitespace, and put them in a list.

Note that you don't need to split on spaces until the last step. It keeps things a lot simpler. Use a for-loop for each step (except step 2), and they'll practically write themselves.

**Edit:** If the last line really means "D followed by (F or G)", I misinterpreted the priority of `|` and `,`. Just split them in opposite order.

Comment: I will try to implement this ! I will let you know about the results!